# Docker Swarm that uses just nodes?

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

If I create a Docker 1.12 Swarm(kit) with e.g. 1 manager and 2 nodes, Swarm will use all 3 hosts to spread containers onto.

I would like to prevent Swarm from using my manager hosts for creating containers. How?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To prevent Docker swarm from publishing containers to a node, you need to set its availability to `pause` or `drain` using :

```
docker node update --availability drain mynode
```

You can to this for all of your managers node

Comment: When I do this, does route mesh (ingris network) ignores the master node then?